# BeautifulSoup cant extract a table from wiki

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When inspecting the table I get

```
<table class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter">
```

so I tried the following in Python:

```
r = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Intel_processors")
x = bs.BeautifulSoup(r.content)
x.find_all("table",{"class":"wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"})
```

However, I get an empty list with this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table class `wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter` does not appear when navigating the website until the column is sorted. I was able to grab exactly one table by using the table class `wikitable sortable`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Intel_processors")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")
tables = soup.find_all("table", class_="wikitable sortable")
print(len(tables))
```

Notes:

- I used `class_=` instead of the dictionary in your example because of the [standford.edu tutorial on Beautiful Soup](http://web.stanford.edu/~zlotnick/TextAsData/Web_Scraping_with_Beautiful_Soup.html).
- A parser was defined in the `BeautifulSoup` class called `html.parser` so the code works on different environments as suggested by the printed warning.

Comment: Thanks, this helped for an issue I was having. Do you have an update to the Stanford link? The current one posted is 404'd.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below approach. It will fetch you the tabular data from that website:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Intel_processors")                                                  
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml') #if you find any problem with "lxml" then try using "html.parser" instead
table = soup.find("table",class_="wikitable")
for items in table.find_all("tr")[:-1]:
    data = [' '.join(item.text.split()) for item in items.find_all(['th','td'])]
    print(data)
```

Partial output:

```
['Processor', 'Series Nomenclature', 'Code Name', 'Production Date', 'Supported Features (Instruction Set)', 'Clock Rate', 'Socket', 'Fabrication', 'TDP', 'Number of Cores', 'Bus Speed', 'L1 Cache', 'L2 Cache', 'L3 Cache', 'Overclock Capable']
['4004', '', '', 'Nov. 15,1971', '', '740 kHz', 'DIP', '10-micron', '', '1 740 kHz', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A']
['8008', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'April 1972', 'N/A', '200 kHz - 800 kHz', 'DIP', '10-micron', '', '1', '200 kHz', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', '']
['8080', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'April 1974', 'N/A', '2 MHz - 3.125 MHz', 'DIP', '6-micron', '', '1', '2 MHz', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', '']
```